# Attribute for XSD to prevent XSD.exe FieldSpecified flags

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I have an xsd file that has the following definition below. When using `xsd.exe` to generate classes from the xsd file, the enum attrs get an additional `FieldSpecified` property as visible below. Unless the `FieldSpecified` property is set, the value will not serialize with the value of the attribute. Is there an additional property I can add to the xsd or a flag I can use with `xsd.exe` to always cause the value to be serialized?

Example from `xsd`:

```
<xs:simpleType name="adrLn">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="ST" />
    <xs:enumeration value="APTN" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

...

<xs:element name="AddressLine" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="AddrLineTypCd" type="adrLn" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Example from generated code:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class RequestCheckIssueAddressAddressLine {

    private adrLn addrLineTypCdField;

    private bool addrLineTypCdFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public adrLn AddrLineTypCd {
        get {
            return this.addrLineTypCdField;
        }
        set {
            this.addrLineTypCdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool AddrLineTypCdSpecified {
        get {
            return this.addrLineTypCdFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.addrLineTypCdFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no flag to change the behaviour - it is all driven by the XSD.

Enums are non nullable. Your attribute is optional (the default value of the **use** attribute in XSD), and so the ***xxxSpecified*** properties are needed to control the serialization of the associated fields (in your case the *addrLineTypCdField* field).

Since you've indicated changing the XSD as a possibility, then the following should fix your issue (make the attribute required):

```
<xs:attribute name="AddrLineTypCd" type="adrLn" use="required" />
```

Comment: I wish it would implement the field with a nullable backing, or flag the field as for serialization if the setter has been used. After posting this I noticed it does this for numeric values too.